# Not able to change the text size in a label when clicking a button

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios5, uibutton

In my iphone app. I want to change the text size in a label when clicking a button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create `UILabel`

```
self.lbl=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(135, 290,200,35)];
    self.lbl.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f",[self.slider value]];
    [self.lbl setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:16]];
    self.lbl.text=str;
    [self.View addSubview:self.lbl];
```

Change size of text of `UILabel` when tapped `UIButton`

```
-(IBAction)ButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    [self.lbl setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:25]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to change the font size at runtime....

```
yourLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction)changeFontOfLabel:(id)sender
{
   [self.lebelObject setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"American Typewriter" size:18];
}
```

and also write the proper font name . check here for a list of [fonts](http://www.prepressure.com/fonts/basics/ios-4-fonts)